# Apple Watch face blank

Tags: apple-watch, reboot

I mistakenly unpaired my Apple Watch from my iPhone. Now the voice over on my watch is on, screen curtain is on, but my screen is blank. I don't know which button to press and I have been trying to pair it back. Since my screen is blank, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting it by holding down the Digital Crown and side button together until you see the Apple logo appear. When that doesn’t work, set it on charge for 15 minutes and repeat. After an hour and no life, you might need a hardware repair or service technician to diagnose it from the service port.